# Should I publish my module's node_modules when doing npm publish?

Tags: npm, publish, node-modules

I am working on a npm module with a couple dependencies. Now, should i publish the dependencies along with my product via the node_modules folder or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you should not.

You should list all your dependencies in your `package.json` and publish that.

Your `node_modules` folder is automatically created when doing an `npm install` of the module, or `npm install` in a directory with a `package.json`.

Comment: but when a project installs my module using `npm install` does that automatically installs my dependencies?

Comment: If they are listed in your package.json